# Early Access student test accounts deleted Google-Classroom

Tags: google-classroom

I was accepted to the developers early access to Google-Classroom on July 8th.

All worked great until August 1st or 2nd when my students..@classroom-dev.com test accounts disappeared. (can no longer log into them, nor do they show up in any classes in classroom.google.com)

My teacher...@classrom-dev.com account still functions fine, can login, and look at the courses I have made. However, now there are no students where there once were.

Also if I try and list students in my courses then I get a "domain not part of developer preview" (it used to work before august 1st)

Is anyone else having problems with their student accounts? mine had only been live for 22 days, so it is not a 30 day trial.

Here are some details, see bottom group for error

```
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list
authenticate=teacher_vkpptkzzgebw60ksbbke@classroom-dev.com
teacherid=me
{
 "courses": [
  {
   "id": "119022294",
   "name": "second class",
   "section": "afternoon",
   "ownerId": "105998884446818928836",
   "creationTime": "2015-07-10T23:18:10.125Z",
   "updateTime": "2015-07-10T23:18:10.125Z",
   "enrollmentCode": "c0kbmfp",
   "courseState": "ACTIVE",
   "alternateLink": "http://classroom.google.com/c/MTE5MDIyMjk0"
  },
  {
   "id": "54694426",
   "name": "Test Course",
   "description": "A test course that was automatically created",
   "ownerId": "105998884446818928836",
   "creationTime": "2015-06-29T20:55:10.032Z",
   "updateTime": "2015-07-10T22:41:43.666Z",
   "enrollmentCode": "r7gskq",
   "courseState": "ACTIVE",
   "alternateLink": "http://classroom.google.com/c/NTQ2OTQ0MjZa"
  }
 ]
}


https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list
authenticate=teacher_vkpptkzzgebw60ksbbke@classroom-dev.com
courseId=119022294
or
courseId=4694426
{
 "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Domain not part of Developer Preview",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
 }
}
```

Comment: The developer preview for the Classroom API is now over and it is open to all developers: http://googleforeducation.blogspot.com/2015/08/general-availability-for-classroom-api.html

Comment: As for the test accounts, as mentioned in the documentation, test accounts expire after 30 days. If you need additional test accounts please fill out the form again.